# Connecting two systems as SQL client-server giving connection error

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, networking, client-server

I am trying to access the database from a remote system connected in local area network. I have done the following settings after googling but nothing has helped me yet:

1. Configured Firewall setting
2. Configured SQL Server Configuration Manager: see here:

[image]

In my Windows services: settings are

[image]

My systems are as follows:

1. `SYSTEM2` - which is working as client
2. `SYSTEM6` - which is working as server

Now what I am able to do is:

1. I am able to access `SYSTEM2` from `SYSTEM6` using my windows `Network Window` and vice-a-verse.

And I have this code on my client machine, which is programmed in `Visual Studio 2010`

```
string conString = "Data Source=SYSTEM6;User ID=sa;Password=mmpass;Initial Catalog=test;";
//So through above connection string what i am trying to do is
//Connecting SYSTEM2 (Which is my client system) to SYSTEM6 (Server system)
public SqlConnection con;

public SqlConnection openConnection()
{
        try
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(conString);
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Close();
                con.Open();
            }
            else
            {
                con.Open();
            }
            return con;
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            return null;
        }
```

The above code causes this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Is there any problem in connection string? Or is there any related settings that I need to change.

**EDIT1:**

I have these settings for Named Pipes:

[image]

You can see that `named Pipes` are disabled and I have this value in it: `\\.\pipe\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS\sql\query`

**EDIT2**

I have this setting for `SQL Native client`

[image]

Comment: Did you have enabled the protocol TCP in the Sql Server Configuration Manager?

Comment: @Steve Yes `TCP/IP` and `Shared Memory` both are enabled on both the systems.

Comment: Strange, but it is using the Named Pipes, you shoul put TCP before Named Pipes in the protocol order

Comment: @Steve I have just done a `EDIT1` kindly go through and suggest. Don't have much exposure to client-server, not so sure about `Named Pipes`. Still now exploring MSDN.

Comment: Check the order of the protocols in Sql Native Client 10.0 Configuration (also for 32 bit) and put the TCP/IP protocol in second position after Shared Memory but before Named Pipes

Comment: @Steve I have an `EDIT2` in my question, kindly suggest now.

Comment: string conString = "Data Source=SYSTEM6\SQLEXPRESS;User ID=sa;Password=mmpass;Initial Catalog=test;";